# How to use $get request in AngularJS after node fetches the data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm building a web app that is going to use an API to display cards when you hover over card text on the app.

I'm using unirest to make the call to the API on my node express server as follows -

```
unirest.get("https://omgvamp-hearthstone-v1.p.mashape.com/cards")
.header("X-Mashape-Key", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
.end(function (result) {
  console.log(result.status, result.headers, result.body);
});
```

The data returns correctly and is displayed in my git bash console as JSON.

How do I use the Angular $get service to make a call against what node has just pulled? I guess my question is , where is this data pulled to once node gets a handle on it?

From what I understand, I would parse this information, but do I have to send this data to use it in my Angular.js file?

I hope I wrote enough information for an answer.

Thank you

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're looking to make use of a `promise`, which can be done by chaining a `.then()` to the request, and then putting the `.get()` inside of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass the data to your UI, you need to make it accessible through an endpoint, so you could do something like this in your server (I'm using express for simplicity):

```
app.get('/my-data-endpoint', (req, res) => {
  unirest.get("https://omgvamp-hearthstone-v1.p.mashape.com/cards")
    .header("X-Mashape-Key", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
    .end((result) => {
      console.log(result.status, result.headers, result.body);
      res.send(result);
    });
});
```

and in your angular controller you can do:

```
$http.get('/my-data-endpoint')
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

just remember to inject the `$http` dependency in your controller and you should be able to see the response.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a go, do I even need to use unirest? I have never used this module before, but the API being hosted on mashape they recommended using it.  Can we just make the app.get call to the mashape https location and set the endpoint in 1 swift motion?  I guess I'm asking if using unirest is redundant?

Comment: The `app.get` is just registering an endpoint within an express server. If you need to do a server to server call (like the one you're handling with unirest) there are multiple projects in npm that can do that for you (unirest seems to be one of them or request [https://www.npmjs.com/package/request ] is a popular one) or you can go native and use the `https` module from node

Comment: Ah I see, would it be more efficient to just make the http$ call to the API directly from angular?  Or does the API prevent the ability to do that because of the API key etc?

Comment: You normally don't want to expose any secrets in the browser, so it makes sense that you would proxy that request with your server